# PHP - how can I mute/replace this Exception handler?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the Facebook PHP API, and around 1 time in 40 it dumps this exception on my webapp:

> Uncaught CurlException: 56: SSL read:
>   error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0),
>   errno 104 thrown in ... on line 638

I'm not looking for a solution to what's causing the exception (already working on that), but **for now I'd like to change it from dumping the exception on the page to either telling the user to refresh the page or refreshing the page automatically.**

The exception is being thrown in this file: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

This is the code I'd like to temporarily change to a refresh / refresh instruction:

```
    if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) { // CURLE_SSL_CACERT
  self::errorLog('Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
              dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
}

if ($result === false) {
  $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error'      => array(
      'message' => curl_error($ch),
      'type'    => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
  curl_close($ch);
  throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TRY .. CATCH` to catch `CurlException`, or `FacebookApiException` there.
Or use [`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to catch any uncaught exception.

Answer (score 1):

As strauberry said, you can stop throwing the exception. If the exception needs to be throw there, you can put the code that call this inside a [try-catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and deal with the exception as you want.

Another option is to use the function [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). This function will be called when an exception is thrown but nothing catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You throw the Exception $e in the last line which causes the dumping. Instead you could do something like

```
echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
```